# How to install AVG Anti-virus without connecting to the internet first?

Tags: installation, avg-antivirus

I want to install an anti-virus, but the downloads (AVG) need me to connect to the internet to install.  Isn't it dangerous to connect to the internet before I've installed the anti-virus?

Oh, and this is an ancient laptop and I've just re-installed Win98 (the only legal OS I had on hand).  But that shouldn't matter.

I do have my XP computer to get the files, and that has the anti-virus installed.

Comment: This was the wrong solution to my problem, but it's still a valid issue: Current anti-virus needs to be installed before connecting to the internet, so an AV install shouldn't require a connection to the internet to install the first time.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you are talking about AVG free.

Take a look at [this page](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download?prd=afg#tba2) and the second download link, it should download the complete installer and not the mini version that downloads from the internet.

[Here is a direct link to the file](http://download.avgfree.com/filedir/inst/avg_free_stf_en_90_716a1803.exe).

Whilst you are at it, you may also want to download the latest virus definitions [from here](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download?prd=afg#tba4).

All this being said, if you are using Windows 98, you may be in trouble because the [documentation](http://download.avgfree.com/filedir/doc/FREE_PRODUCTS/AVG_Free/avg_afg_uma_en_90_9.pdf) says that the latest supported version of Windows is 2000.

Comment: Yes, I see that Win98 isn't supported.  I really just want to get the drivers I need to get this thing working, for word processing (I have CDs) and for the USB driver (another install that seems to want to connect to install).  After that, it won't be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

**[Avast! Home Edition](http://www.avast.com/eng/download-avast-home.html)** still supports Windows 98 (free registration after 60 days required)

Note: their installer requires an internet connection, you can get the FULL installer at **[FileHippo.com](http://www.filehippo.com/download_avast_antivirus/)**

**[Kaspersky Anti-Virus For Windows Workstations](http://www.kaspersky.com/anti-virus_windows_workstation)** also supports Windows 98, the free 30-days trial should suffice for what you have in mind.

You can download Kaspersky Anti-Virus For Windows Workstations in the *For Business* section.